# CSS issue on Safari on Mac

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-accounts

When browsing a user profile with Safari on Mac this happens:
[image]

On hover, the reputation underline is mispositioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put in a fix. It will be in the next production build.